# What Did the Michelson-Morley Experiment Say about the Speed of Light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, history, aether

In the quotation below, does Banesh Hoffmann, Einstein's collaborator, admit that originally ("without recourse to contracting lengths, local time, or Lorentz transformations") the Michelson-Morley experiment directly proved Newton's variable speed of light and disproved the constant speed of light?

> "Moreover, if light consists of particles, as Einstein had suggested in his paper submitted just thirteen weeks before this one, the second principle seems absurd: A stone thrown from a speeding train can do far more damage than one thrown from a train at rest; the speed of the particle is not independent of the motion of the object emitting it. And if we take light to consist of particles and assume that these particles obey Newton's laws, they will conform to Newtonian relativity and thus automatically account for the null result of the Michelson-Morley experiment without recourse to contracting lengths, local time, or Lorentz transformations. Yet, as we have seen, Einstein resisted the temptation to account for the null result in terms of particles of light and simple, familiar Newtonian ideas, and introduced as his second postulate something that was more or less obvious when thought of in terms of waves in an ether." (Banesh Hoffmann, Relativity and Its Roots, p.92 [https://www.amazon.com/Relativity-Its-Roots-Banesh-Hoffmann/dp/0486406768](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486406768))

Answer (score 2):

No. The Michelson Morley experiment is consistent with both the ballistic theory of light (Newton’s idea referenced in the question) and special relativity. An experiment cannot rule out or disprove any theory that it is consistent with.

The Michelson Morley experiment was also consistent with the Lorentz aether theory and a fully dragged aether theory. The main theory that it is inconsistent with is a rigid aether theory.

The ballistic theory is ruled out by binary star observations. Dragged aether theories are ruled out by Sagnac interferometer experiments.

Note that the “without recourse ...” part of the quote is referring to Newton’s laws, not the experiment. So he is simply stating the obvious fact that Newton’s theory does not include those effects. There is no implication that those effects are not present in the Michelson Morley experiment, and certainly no implication that relativity is therefore disproved by this experiment.

Comment: Originally, "without recourse to contracting lengths, local time, or Lorentz transformations", the Michelson-Morley experiment was only consistent with Newton's variable speed of light, c'=c±v.

Comment: I added a paragraph directly addressing that portion of the quote

Comment: Originally, the constant (independent of the speed of the emitter) speed of light, c'=c, was inconsistent with the null result of the experiment (only c'=c±v was consistent). By introducing, ad hoc, contracting lengths etc., Fitzgerald and Lorentz made it consistent.

Comment: Comments are not for discussion. It is simply not true that only the ballistic model is consistent with the MM experiment. Consistent is consistent, even if it is ad hoc (although Einstein’s approach is not ad hoc at all)